# Why is my tkinter program writing numbers to a file instead of the actual values?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a tkinter program that writes the user's data to a file, but when writing the variable they turn into numbers.

This is what is being written to the file:

```
 .15212688
 .15213328
 .15213232
  INVALID REGISRATION NUMBER
```

And this is my code:

```
def show_entry_fields():#creates a function called show entry fields. 
    print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nRegistration number:%s" % (Fname.get(), Lname.get(), reg.get()))
    if re.match('^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}$', reg.get()):#validates the users reg number by ching that its in the correct format 
        w.configure(text='That is a valid registration number')# if the reg is valid, tells user
    
    else:
        w.configure(text='Invalid registration number')#user is told that reg is not valid 
        data = open("invalid.txt", "w")#users data is writen to a file called 'invalid'
        data.write(str(Fname))#first name
        data.write('\n')#new line 
        data.write(str(Lname))#last name
        data.write('\n')#new line
        data.write(str(reg))# the casr's regitration number 
        data.write('\n')#new line 
        data.write('INVALID REGISRATION NUMBER')# the perpiose of being writen to the file

        data.close()#closes the file when finished.
```

Comment: You ask why it won't write to a file, but then you say it _is_ writing to a file. You might want to change the title to be more accurate. The problem isn't that it won't write to a file, it's that it's not writing what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
data.write(str(Fname.get()))#first name
data.write('\n')#new line 
data.write(str(Lname.get()))#last name
data.write(str(reg.get()))
```

In *your* code you're converting *objects* to strings.